# window.scroll(0,0)/window.scrollTo(0, 0) are not working on mobile in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I tried for a long time to make window.scroll(0,0) to work on the mobile version in Chrome. Then I discovered that my code worked when I removed the "mobile view" from devtools. Why is not scrolling to top working on mobile, but working on desktop?

E.g. if I click on the "next" button in a scheme my function is something like this:

```
handleNext = () => {
  ...
  window.scroll(0,0);
}
```

And this works just fine for desktop. I have also tried `window.scrollTo`. The same is happening: scrolling to the top on desktop, and nothing is happening in mobile.

Here is a screenshot of the element which is "overflowing" It is not any specific element. The div is just building the body so high that you need to scroll inside the chrome. So the scroll is completely inside the chrome, and not inside an element.

Comment: can you post some code samples

Comment: @tvankith I added example to my question

Comment: Can you post an example of the utilization? only the js will work in a different context.

Comment: Rather than "something like", can you show the exact code that causes this to kick in? And related, can you show the dev console's output when you run this because it's entirely possible it has errors _before_ that scroll call (remote debugging Chrome is [pretty simple](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/))

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this doesn't work when the overflowed element is not the main/body/html.

You need to make the overflowed element scroll top.

You can see more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp)

Comment: I am pretty sure that my content is so tall that the scrollbar is on the whole "page", and not inside a component.

Comment: Can you inspect that overflowed element and post a print screen here?

Comment: Edited, leaving only the possible answer

Comment: I added a screenshot. As you can see there is no scroll inside any div or any other elements. The scroll is inside the chrome